# Setting a Polygon Visibility from TextBlock style

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datatrigger

I'm having a small issue anyones suggestions are appreciated so much.

[image: im trying to display something like this]

**Problem:**
I'm getting my value in `RowData.Row.ScannedQty` in this prop. and I'm sending it to this `WarehouseInventoryDefineValueConvertor` and checking whether the value is zero or Plus or Minus based on that I added the + or - but the problem is setting the Visibility of the Polygon I  cant use like this as the Dp is not bindable how can I achieve this?

**Solutions I considered:**

1.Using a proxy TextBlock save the value there and use it in DataTrigger

2.calling my converter on every Polygon (this is an option i wanna avoid this as the call for the converter is increased by 4 times)

```
 <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Name="TxtScannedQty" Text="{Binding RowData.Row.ScannedQty,Converter={UIConverter:WarehouseInventoryDefineValueConvertor}}" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <TextBlock.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                    <Setter Property="{Binding ElementName=MinusPolygon,Path=Visibility}" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=TxtScannedQty,Path=Text}" Value="Zero">
                            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding RowData.Row.ScannedQty, StringFormat= {}{0}}"></Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=TxtScannedQty,Path=Text}" Value="Plus">
                            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding RowData.Row.ScannedQty, StringFormat= +{}{0}}"></Setter>
                            <Setter Property="{Binding ElementName=MinusPolygon,Path=Visibility}" Value="Visble"></Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=TxtScannedQty,Path=Text}" Value="Minus">
                            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding RowData.Row.ScannedQty, StringFormat= -{}{0}}"></Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBlock.Style>
        </TextBlock>
        <Grid>
            <Polygon Name="PlusPolygon"   Points="5,0 10,10, 0,10" Stroke="Green" Fill="Green" />
            <Polygon Name="MinusPolygon" Points="0,0 5,10, 10,0" Stroke="Red" Fill="Red" />
            <Line Name="Zero1" Stroke="Gray" X1="0" Y1="2" X2="10" Y2="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"   StrokeThickness="2" />
            <Line Name="Zero2" Stroke="Gray" X1="0" Y1="4" X2="10" Y2="4" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"   StrokeThickness="2" />
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
```

**Based on answer**

I end up calling converter 3 times is there any better way to do it ?

```
<Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RowData.Row.ScannedQty,Converter={UIConverter:WarehouseInventoryDefineValueConvertor}Value="Zero">
                    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ZeroTemplate}" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RowData.Row.ScannedQty,Converter={UIConverter:WarehouseInventoryDefineValueConvertor}}" Value="Plus">
                    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource PositiveTemplate}" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RowData.Row.ScannedQty,Converter={UIConverter:WarehouseInventoryDefineValueConvertor}}" Value="Minus">
                    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource NegativeTemplate}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of different ways to solve this, I generally do it by templating an existing control e.g. something like this:

```
<Control>
    <Control.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Control">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SomeBoundProperty}" Value="Zero">
                    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ZeroTemplate}" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SomeBoundProperty}" Value="Plus">
                    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource PositiveTemplate}" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SomeBoundProperty}" Value="Minus">
                    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource NegativeTemplate}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Control.Style>
</Control>
```

And then you declare each template in your resources block however you like:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ZeroTemplate" TargetType="Control">
    <Grid>
        <!-- etc -->
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

That way the only elements in the visual tree are the ones that are actually visible.

I've used a generic control here, but you could of course also use your TextBlock and then just put a ContentPresenter or something where you want the actual text to appear in the child templates.

Comment: I added small brock in question can please take look please

Comment: @AvinashReddy: Don't use a converter then. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to create a custom control or a `UserControl`, you could set the `Tag` property of the `TextBlock` to a `Visibility` value and then bind the `Polygon`'s `Visibility` property to the `Tag` property of the `TextBlock`:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Name="TxtScannedQty" Text="{Binding RowData.Row.ScannedQty, Converter={UIConverter:WarehouseInventoryDefineValueConvertor}}" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                <Setter Property="Tag" Value="Collapsed" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=TxtScannedQty,Path=Text}" Value="Zero">
                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding RowData.Row.ScannedQty, StringFormat= {}{0}}"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=TxtScannedQty,Path=Text}" Value="Plus">
                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding RowData.Row.ScannedQty, StringFormat= +{}{0}}"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="Tag" Value="Visible"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=TxtScannedQty,Path=Text}" Value="Minus">
                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding RowData.Row.ScannedQty, StringFormat= -{}{0}}"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>
    <Grid>
        <Polygon Name="PlusPolygon" Points="5,0 10,10, 0,10" Stroke="Green" Fill="Green">
            <Polygon.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Polygon">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Visibility, ElementName=MinusPolygon}" Value="Visible">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Polygon.Style>
        </Polygon>
        <Polygon Name="MinusPolygon" Points="0,0 5,10, 10,0" Stroke="Red" Fill="Red"
                         Visibility="{Binding Tag, ElementName=TxtScannedQty}" />
        <Line Name="Zero1" Stroke="Gray" X1="0" Y1="2" X2="10" Y2="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"   StrokeThickness="2" />
        <Line Name="Zero2" Stroke="Gray" X1="0" Y1="4" X2="10" Y2="4" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"   StrokeThickness="2" />
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

If you don't want to "call the converter 3 times", you should return "Zero", "Plus" or "Minus" from the source property in the view model instead of converting the value in the view.